# Lasers safe to watch in video

Tags: laser

Probably sounds silly but paranoid.  Can you watch in a video a class 4 laser?  Is that ok? Watched a couple videos of lasers on YouTube and know I am paranoid.

Comment: I'm cutting to close this question because it is about possible health hazards and not physics

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry i'm sure you'll be fine. The light you will see in the video is generated by your computer screen; although it will be the same colour as the laser, your computer screen cant generate the same kind of power as a class 4 laser so the light will not damage your eyes. Happy watching!

Comment: If monitors were capable of laser-level power, that would be a huge security/health issue.  Just imagine hackers purposefully blinding people.

Comment: Not even starting to talk about movies from atomic tests.